# Unexpected saturation with the rail to rail instrumental amplifier AD623

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, saturation

I'm trying to use the rail-to-rail instrumental amplifier AD623. [Here the datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD623.pdf).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYrUSd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**First experiment:**
AD623 set as a voltage follower. Gain = 1 obtained by removing  the Rg resistance between Rg-  and Rg+ pin.

Everything goes right until I reach 4.3 V (read with VM1 and VM2)
4.3 V is the maximum amplifier output even when the difference between inputs is 5V.
But this is a rail-to-rail amplifier...

**Second experiment:**
AD623 set with gain = 2 (using a 100K resistor in according to datasheet).

Everything goes right until I reach 2 V of difference between inputs.(read with VM1)
In this case 4.0 V is the maximum amplifier output.

Under this value the amplifier works good (if in input I have 1V in output I read 2V)

**Other information:**

- +Vs = +5V
- -Vs = GND
- REF = GND

How is it possible?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks for help (and sorry for my poor english)

Comment: Are you providing a path for input bias current?  It's not clear that you are from the schematic you provide.  See page 19 of the data sheet.

Comment: you are right! I completely forgot the bias current. 3 hours ago there was another answer below, but now is disappear.
They say that AD623 isn't a rail-to-rail Amplifier.
The presence of bias current can produce, in this case, a difference between theorical and real output of few mV, it's true?

Comment: I think the now removed answer was that the *input* isn't rail to rail but that wouldn't account for your result with gain 2 so I'm guessing that's why it was removed.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Anthony I think so, that was an old project and, at the end, was a success. In the 2nd prototipe the problem was no longer present. I think the problem was a simple mistake but after 5 year I don’t remember... I should have written it here. Are you experience the same problem?

Comment: Ok, that's good. No, not yet. My AD623s are in the mail, I was just checkig to see if I misunderstood anything about them. You know, sonetimes dataaheets can make things appear better than they are :)

Comment: Don’t worry AD623 it’s a good differential amplifier. I used this component to amplify small signal from load cell.